# Model is observable, but why doesn't the EKF implementation converge to correct values?

Tags: control-theory, kalman-filter

I have a vector field (unable to provide the details, unfortunately) $$\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x,u)$$ and measurements $$y = g(x,u)$$

Linearizing around any $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{u}$, I verified that the linearized pair $(A,C)$ is observable, as long as the first state, $x_1$, is non-zero. In practice, this occurs if the system is perpetually excited in some manner.

However, when actually implementing the EKF, I found that the states do not converge to the correct values, even when the aforementioned condition is met. Any idea how this could be? How could the EKF, which is an optimal observer, fail to observe the states when the linearized pair is observable?

Comment: Some thoughts. How close is your initial guess for the state? It is important that your initial guess be reasonably close for highly nonlinear systems. EKF doesn't guarantee global convergence. Secondly, it is required that the pair be observable *at* the true configuration. Is this the case? Also, EKF is not an optimal observer in any real sense. The kalman filter is for a linear system in some specific sense.

Comment: @RollenD'Souza Could you elaborate on "observable at the true configuration"?

Comment: If the system is at state $x,$ the system's linearization at $x$ is observable. So nothing out of the ordinary, and I think it is the case based on your last sentence.

Comment: Are you by any change trying to implement the discrete time EKF algorithm for the continues time nonlinear model without discretizing first?

Comment: @RollenD'Souza Yes, EKF is linearized at every operating point.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen No, it's discretized. It's not a stiff system so I don't expect discretization to be the problem here.

Comment: I think you probably have to provide a bit more details about your system, ideally a minimal working example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "implementing the EKF"? Are you applying it to data gathered from a system, which is assumed to have that dynamics? Or are you running a simulation using the dynamical model, and if so are you also adding in disturbances and/or noise?

Comment: Also what discretization method are you using? Have you tried other methods and have you tried decreasing the time step size?